# Do Backbone models share state by default

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have two instances of a model and find that they seem to share state across them. I would have thought the opposite would occur. For instance:

```
var Q =     Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    fooObj: {
      bar: {}
    }
  },
  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'addFoo');
  },
  addFoo: function(f) {
        //get fooObj
        fo = this.get('fooObj');
        fo.bar[1] = f;
        //set it back
        this.set('fooObj', fo);
      }, 
  getFoo: function (argument) {
        return this.get('fooObj');

  }
})

q1 = new Q();
q2 = new Q();

q1.addFoo({iam: 'foo'});
console.log(q2.getFoo().bar[1]); // {iam : "foo"}
```

Although I add `{iam: "foo"}` to instance `q1`, it seems to get propagated to `q2` too. Am I missing a trick here? It appears `get` and `set` is the right safe way to access model data, and yet it results in this behaviour (or is this expected)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the `fooObj` will be shared because you are creating just one at model definition time.

Instead create your defaults with a function (see the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults)):

```
defaults: function() {
  return {
    fooObj: {
      bar: {}
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: The docs even say: *Remember that in JavaScript, objects are passed by reference, so if you include an object as a default value, it will be shared among all instances.*